# Close menu when clicking outside the React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, dom-events, onclicklistener

I have a menu component which I want to close when I click anywhere on the page if it’s open.

Is there a way to close the menu without the need for an event listener being added to the document and checking the `event.target`.

There is no way to send the close function back upto the parent component as it lives on a separate `Route`.

```
Navbar
-> MenuComponent
RouteView
-> MainContent
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. This is easily accomplished by wrapping the component in the ClickAwayListener provided by material ui. Then you pass a function to the onClickAway attribute and that should close your menu for you. I've provided a template below and you can also check out the MUI [docs](https://mui.com/components/click-away-listener/):

```
import ClickAwayListener from '@mui/material/ClickAwayListener';

export default function MenuComponent() {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => {
    setOpen(!open);
  };

  const handleClickAway = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  return (
    <ClickAwayListener onClickAway={handleClickAway}>
      <Box>
        <button type="button" onClick={handleClick}>
          Open menu dropdown
        </button>
        {open ? (
          <Box>
            Click me, I will stay visible until you click outside.
          </Box>
        ) : null}
      </Box>
    </ClickAwayListener>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This looks like it’ll do the job.

Comment: OMG thank you this helped me so much, such simplicity!